# Get nth row after applying lambda on groupby in python

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

So I need to group a dataframe by its SessionId, and then I need to sort each group with the created time, afterwards i need to retrieve the nth row only of each group.

but i found that after applying lambda it becomes a dataframe instead of a group by object, hence i cannot use the .nth property

```
grouped = df.groupby(['SessionId'])

sorted = grouped.apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(["Created"], ascending = True))

sorted.nth  ---> error
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the order in which you are approaching the problem in this case will help. If you first sort and then use groupby, you will get the desired output and you can use the groupby.nth function.

Here is a code snippet to demonstrate the idea:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id':['a','a','a','b','b','b'],
                  'var1':[3,2,1,8,7,6],
                  'var2':['g','h','i','j','k','l']})

n = 2 # replace with required row from each group

df.sort_values(['id','var1']).groupby('id').nth(n).reset_index()
```

Assuming `id` is your sessionid and `var1` is the timestamp, this sorts your dataframe by `id` and then `var1`. Then picks up the `n`th row from each of these sorted groups. The `reset_index()` is there just to avoid the resulting multi-index.

If you want to get the last `n` rows of each group, you can use `.tail(n)` instead of `.nth(n)`.

Comment: thanks, may I know if i set n = 9 what would happen to groups with less than 9 row?

Comment: Those particular groups will not have any corresponding rows in the final dataframe in that case. So you will only see rows from the groups which have `n` rows

Answer (score 1):

I have created a small dataset -

[image]

```
n = 2
grouped = df.groupby('SessionId')
pd.concat([grouped.get_group(x).sort_values(by='SortVar').reset_index().loc[[n]] for x in grouped.groups]\
          ,axis=0)
```

This will return -

[image]

Please note that in python index start from zero, so for n=2, it will give you 3rd row in sorted data